# Twilio doesn't send verification codes for Caller ID to non-US numbers

Tags: twilio, caller-id

My client gave me their Twilio account with a trial plan, registered in the US (perhaps this matters). I was trying to add my numbers to the Caller IDs using the web UI. Eventually I've got no codes for either ukrainian or spanish numbers, but it works fine with US numbers.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Messaging or Verify (which I would recommend) to send the messages?

In either case, make sure you set the appropriate [Geo permissions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/preventing-toll-fraud/verify-geo-permissions#:%7E:text=You%20can%20access%20the%20Verify,country%20and%20then%20click%20Save) so you are able to send messages to international numbers.